# Switch between two identical network printers

Tags: windows-7, networking, ip, network-printer

I have two network printers from the same manufacturer and having the same model and driver.

To avoid load on one printer, I divided my users into two Teams (Team A and Team B)

**Printer 1** with IP : 192.168.0.100 (used by *Team A*)

**Printer 2** with IP : 192.168.0.200 (used by Team B)

Is there any easy way to let *Team B* switch to **Printer 1** and vice versa in

case one of the printers is out of work without the need to modify the IP on

their computers one by one or even install it again with the other IP. We are using Windows 7.

Comment: Can you simply install both printers on all and set some of the users to use printer 1 as default and the rest to use printer2 as their default?

Comment: What is the environment in which you want to accomplish this?

Comment: All my users have Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

There are various way going about this, the most simplest way with your setup at the moment is to grant access to both printers to each user. Then set half of the defaults to Printer 1 and the other half of the user default to Printer 2. In this case if one of the printers is off or the users can select the next available printer.

The other way to accomplish this is through load balancing or pooling your printers through a print server. This may come in handy when you expand and have 3, 4, 5+ printers in a work environment. If this seems more like the direction you want to head I recommend you read about [Print Management](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753109(v=ws.10).aspx) from Microsoft. This is possible on other systems but since you all are on Windows 7, sticking with Microsoft seems like a smart way to go.